# CSS: Why menu border doesn't appear when the scroll bar appears?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

<kbd>[**LIVE DEMO**](http://jsbin.com/macoyalu/1/edit)</kbd>

Consider the following menu example: (note the red border)

[image]

```
<div class="menu-wrapper">
  <div class="menu-item">Hello</div>
  <div class="menu-item">Stack</div>
  <div class="menu-item">Overflow</div>
</div>

.menu-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: #ccc;
  border-left: 5px solid #bbb;
  height: 300px;
}
.menu-item {
  padding: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.menu-item:hover {
  margin-left: -5px;
  background-color: #444;
  color: #fff;
  border-left: 5px solid red;
}
```

Now, imagine that the height of `menu-wrapper` is small, and we want the vertical scroll bar to appear. For example, we could replace:

```
height: 300px;
```

with:

```
height: 100px;
overflow-y: auto;
```

But, [the red border disappears then](http://jsbin.com/yavujeyi/1/edit):

[image]

Why is that? How would you fix that?

<kbd>[**PLAYGROUND HERE**](http://jsbin.com/rohujipa/1/edit)</kbd>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since overflow hides what overflows, you may instead draw the border on the background or with an inset shadow , so it is drawn on the whole height of cntainer : **[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/rohujipa/13/edit)**

```
.menu-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: #ccc;
  box-shadow: inset 5px 0  #bbb;/* here draws an inside left border via shadow */
  height: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  overflow:auto;
}
.menu-item {
  padding: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.menu-item:hover {
  background-color: #444;
  color: #fff;
  border-left: 5px solid red;
}
```

Comment: Very nice, thanks! Apparently, adding `flex-shrink: 0;` to `menu-item` solves also the bottom padding issue: http://jsbin.com/katagara/1/edit

Answer (score 2):

I think [this works](http://jsbin.com/rohujipa/3/):

The problem is that the red border of `menu-item` is *hiding* behind the grey border of the `menu-wrapper`. So, I removed the border from the wrapper and put it in the item, like this:

```
.menu-wrapper {
  ...      
  /* border-left: 5px solid #bbb;    No longer needed */
  height: 100px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
.menu-item {
  padding: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-left: 5px solid #bbb; /* Add border to menu-item rather than the wrapper */
}
.menu-item:hover {
  /* margin-left: -5px;    No longer needed*/
  background-color: #444;
  color: #fff;
  border-left: 5px solid red;
}
```

**Note:** The grey border of the menu-wrapper doesn't take the full height anymore. You could use `box-shadow` on the wrapper ([as answered by GCyrillus](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23538481/1492578)) to fix this.

You could *integrate* both the solutions, so the design won't look too bad in older browsers where `box-shadow` isn't supported.

```
.menu-wrapper {
    ...
    box-shadow: inset 5px 0 #bbb;
}
```

Comment: Your solution solves the red border issue, but has a regression: the grey border of the `menu-wrapper` doesn't take the full height anymore: http://jsbin.com/tutihuwa/1/edit

Comment: Yes, I agree. The OP could use `box-shadow` on the wrapper as pointed by GCyrillus.